# Login works with request session but not with request_html session

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

So, I'm perplexed by this and can't seem to find an answer online. I build a payload:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}

payload = { 
    'login[username]': 'username',
    'login[password]': 'password',
    'form_key': token # scraped from site
}
```

Then I send it with a requests session:

```
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = headers
p = session.post(LOGIN_POST_URL, data=payload)
```

And I'm able to log in (verified by following up with a `session.get()`). However, I need to render JavaScript and as a learning exercise, I'm trying to do it without `selenium` by using `requests_html`. However, if I try:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session2 = HTMLSession()
session2.headers = headers
session2.post(LOGIN_POST_URL,data=payload)
```

I'm unable to log in, as verified with a subsequent `.get()` request. I've tried the latter in isolation to make sure I'm not being throttled by the server, and no dice. Does anyone have an idea what the difference between the two sessions might be? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you provide an url ? If the website is free to register on, it may be helpfull

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the website isn't free (need to register to see wholesale prices). I've moved on to just use selenium, but still would love to see if folks have encountered this issue.